# Change scale on X axis in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot (Line graph) and trying to plot my data by week, however when I am plotting the data R automatically shows the weeks by 10, 15, ....
I want o show all the weeks number on my X Axis, e.g. 10,11,12,...

[image]

Comment: Hi Pegah, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(data)` or if your data is very large `dput(data[1:20,])`. You should replace `data` with the name of your actual data. You can [edit] your question and paste the output. Please surround the output with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Comment: Hi OP - can you share some of your dataset or at least the structure of the column that corresponds to your x axis?  Is it just numeric, or is it a Date/POSIXct class?

Comment: Hi, I added the picture in my question, my X Axis data is already Week number, (10, 11, 12, ....)  , R Automatically hide the week numbers and just show 10, 15 , ....

Answer (score 3):

It seems your "weeks" axis is numeric (just the number) rather than a date.  To change where the tick marks are indicated for your axis, you can use the `breaks=` argument of `scale_*_continuous()` for the numeric scale.  Here's an example where you can see how to do this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:20, y=rnorm(20))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
p
```

[image]

By default, the x axis is separated into major breaks of 5.  If you wanted breaks every 1, you supply a vector to the `breaks=` argument:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,20,by=1))
```

[image]

You can even do odd things, like specify breaks individually if you want:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,5,10,11,12,18,20))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the step by step procedure

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(...) + geom_line(...) + scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 30)
```

You can modify the **n.breaks** parameter to your liking.